# Openning a PostGIS shapefile using django in web app

Tags: python, django, leaflet, geoserver

I created a django app that connects to Geoserver and PostGIS database. The intention is to create a web app using Leaflet, django and PostGIS connection. I add the data to PostGIS and import do django. However everytime appears these errors:

```
Object 'parsererror' Error: getJson was not called

    at Function.error (jquery.min.js:2)

    at e.converters.script json (jquery.min.js:2)

    at jquery.min.js:2

    at l (jquery.min.js:2)

    at HTMLScriptElement.i (jquery.min.js:2)

    at HTMLScriptElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)

    at HTMLScriptElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Then it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getJson is not defined
```

In the django (index.html) the shapefile is requested to Geoserver as WFS, as this:

```
var wfsLayer_solos = L.Geoserver.wfs("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs", {
  layers: "gic:solos1_2_4326",
  style: {
    color: "black",
    fillOpacity: "0",
    opacity: "0.5",
  },
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(feature.properties,null,' ').replace(/[\{\}"]/g,'')+'</pre>');
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated from the `leaflet-geoserver-request` library. The error happens when you put the wrong layer name into the `layers` parameter. The `layers` parameter will only support the features, i.e. vector layers. Please also add the layer to the map as below,

```js
wfsLayer_solos.addTo(map);
```

Comment: What is the layers parameter? Because I am adding to the map like this: var groupedOverlays = {
  "Terrain analysis": {
    "Aspect Dezembro 2019": wms_aspect_dez_2019,
    "Aspect Julho 2019":wms_aspect_julho_2019,
  },
  "Soil and water samples": {
    "Soil samples": wfsLayer_solos
  }
};

L.control.groupedLayers(baseLayers, groupedOverlays).addTo(map);